# Installing DBSqlite Browser on Ubuntu

Tags: database, sqlite3

I tried to install DBSqlite Browser for [Ubuntu and Derivatives](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/).

After installation, I enter the command to open Ubuntu in the terminal: "sqlitebrowser" and the following crashes:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. 
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

A holistic solution to the problem could not be found. Various tips like sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0 did not help

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 
DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.2
Built for x86_64-little_endian-llp64, running on x86_64
Qt Version 5.12.8
Версия SQLite 3.35.5.
```

Comment: Could you try run it in Gnome X session: logout, select your account, look for session option button and select Xorg session, enter password to login again.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add the PPA for the [nightly builds](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser-testing) instead, since the `sqlitebrowser` package in the [stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser) has not been updated for 2 years (and as such do not include a version for Ubuntu 22.04).

Uninstall the current version, and remove the stable PPA. Then add the unstable PPA (which has a version for Ubuntu 22.04)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing
```

And then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

This should install a working version (although the "unstable" branch).

If you need another version, you would have to [compile it yourself](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/BUILDING.md#build-instructions-and-requirements).

Comment: 1.sudo apt-get remove sqlitebrowser
2.sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser
3.sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing
4.sudo apt-get update
5.sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
6.sqlitebrowser.





Unfortunately it didn't help. The result is the same (((